# is it possible to add iad to html web app

Tags: iphone, html, iad

I want to **add iAD** to HTML web app.
Just wonder if it is possible.
Do I need to contract framework simulate iAD framework by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add iAd to a web app, only native iOS apps. I would look into Google's advertisement service, or a different one.